# Perf Collects Call Graphs only for Some Samples

Tags: linux, caching, trace, perf, call-graph

I ran the following command to sample a simple benchmark on `evince`:

```
sudo perf record -d --call-graph lbr -c 10 -e mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss:uppp evince
```

This is a `PEBS`-based sampling with a period of `10` events. I viewed the result of profiling using the following command:

```
sudo perf mem report
```

But, as shown below, only the first two samples have backtraces. How can I have backtraces for all samples?

```
# To display the perf.data header info, please use --header/--header-only options.
#
#
# Total Lost Samples: 0
#
# Samples: 28K of event 'mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss:uppp'
# Total weight : 28529
# Sort order   : local_weight,mem,sym,dso,symbol_daddr,dso_daddr,snoop,tlb,locked
#
# Overhead       Samples  Local Weight  Memory access             Symbol                                                                                               
# ........  ............  ............  ........................  .....................................................................................................
#
     2.44%           696  0             N/A                       0xffffffff87a00ae7 ! [k] 0xffffffff87a00ae7                                                          
            |          
             --1.25%--_ZN3Gfx7doImageEP6ObjectP6Streamb
                       |          
                        --1.20%--   _ZN14CairoOutputDev9drawImageEP8GfxStateP6ObjectP6StreamiiP16GfxImageColorMapbPib
                                  |          
                                   --0.77%--_ZN16GfxImageColorMap10getRGBLineEPhPji
                                             _ZN21GfxICCBasedColorSpace10getRGBLineEPhPji

     1.08%           309  0             N/A                       0xffffffff87a00ae7 ! [k] 0xffffffff87a00ae7                                                          
            |          
             --0.70%--_ZN3Gfx7doImageEP6ObjectP6Streamb
                       |          
                        --0.58%--_ZN14CairoOutputDev9drawImageEP8GfxStateP6ObjectP6StreamiiP16GfxImageColorMapbPib
                                  _ZN16GfxImageColorMap10getRGBLineEPhPji
                                  _ZN21GfxICCBasedColorSpace10getRGBLineEPhPji

     0.52%           148  0             N/A                       0x18ef2d           u [.] __memset_avx2_erms                                                          
     0.29%            83  0             N/A                       0x18eb1f           u [.] __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms                                                
     0.24%            69  0             N/A                       0xffffffff87a00ae7 ! [k] 0xffffffff87a00ae7                                                          
     0.22%            62  0             N/A                       0x3cc9c            D [.] bits_image_fetch_separable_convolution_affine_pad_x8r8g8b8                  
     0.21%            59  0             N/A                       0x18eb1f           u [.] __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms
```

Comment: Hello, could you check output of `perf script` command when started in the directory with your perf.data file? It should print raw data (samples) from perf.data and it will also decode function names. What is the exact linux kernel version used and exact CPU model?

Comment: `perf script` prints callgraphs for each single event, while `perf mem report` reports very few of them. `perf report` is much better than `perf mem report`, but it still misses some callgraphs.

Comment: I think there may be some bug in perf report handling and merging of call traces. It can be possible to try different perf version for report (perf is distributed and compiled with some version of linux kernel, but actually have wide range of compatibility with different kernel versions). I do not know anything about `perf mem report` and how it is different from `perf report`. You can try alternative merging tools of perf.data ("perf script" output), for example flamegraphs http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html#Instructions

Comment: The problem is that I can not access some information provided by `perf mem report` in the `perf script` output. For example, `perf mem report` can tell if the accessed memory address is inside `[heap]`, is `//anon` or is inside a shared library. But I can not find a similar classification in `perf script`.